# git-tfs branches=all not working

Tags: git, tfs, git-tfs

I'm trying to migrate our TFS repository to Git. I'm using git-tfs to migrate.
I have a problem occurring and one doubt. When I try to migrate using `branches=all` it comes to a point where it does not continue (see image below).

If I can not migrate all branches once I can migrate each branch in a separate repository. But I can then take these separate repositories and create a single repository converting each repository in a branch?

[image: Migration with branches=all]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a known behaviour in complex blanching pattern (seems to be when a branch has been deleted and another created with the same name...).

There is no solution until someone dig in the problem and fix it. 
But there is a some dirty workaround. See in git-tfs issues:
https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues

Cloning each branch, one by one is not a good idea because it will take you a lot of time and you won't be able to go further than git-tfs will bring you.

Comment: Hummm thank you :)
Im my case we will change tfs to gitlab. Then i have the ideia to migrate each branch and then merge all. this is possible?

Comment: Hello, after one more test the migration works.
* Clone only the Trunk then init all branches and all works fine, my branch 12.3 don´t crash everything :D
thanks.